# It doesn't run the first time

Tags: cron

Trying to run cron tasks using `0 */1 * * * root curl -s http://site.name/cron.php?cron_key=secret_key >> /var/log/site-cron.log 2>&1` or `0 */1 * * * root wget -O - -q -t 1 http://site.name/cron.php?cron_key=secretkey >> /var/log/site-cron.log 2>&1` doesn't work.

Using `0 */1 * * * root curl -s http://site.name/cron.php?cron_key=secret_key >> /var/log/site-cron.log 2>&1` and `2 */1 * * * root curl -s http://site.name/cron.php?cron_key=secret_key >> /var/log/site-cron.log 2>&1`, the second attempt works.

Access log shows both calls, but dblog shows only the second attempt.
There are no errors in nginx log, cron log, php-fpm log.

How do I fix this?

UPD: thanks @zhilevan. I was able to debug cron scripts with his help. This way `drush --root=/usr/share/nginx/demo --quiet cron` displays errors in cron scripts.

Comment: does your site hosted on the same server your crontab created?

Comment: @zhilevan, yes, same server

Comment: did you try my latest solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your source code and crontab on the same server I suggest try to run internally by PHP, Try something like

```
0 */1 * * * root  /usr/bin/php /home/sites/example.com/public_html/cron.php
```

- **/usr/bin/php** = your php path
- **/home/sites/example.com/public_html/** = your site source code path

For getting more information read [Configuring cron jobs using the cron command](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron-for-drupal/configuring-cron-jobs-using-the-cron-command).

**Update: Solution 2 : create bash script**

```
touch ~/scripts/cron-php.sh
chmod 700 ~/scripts/cron-php.sh
vi ~/scripts/cron-php.sh
```

filled it with

```
#!/bin/bash
root_path=/usr/share/nginx/demo/
parse=/usr/bin/php

# PHP parser options
#
# Defaulting to not report notices.
parse_options="-d error_reporting=2037"

# Verbosity
#
# Default to only report errors.
verbose=false


cd $root_path

if [ -e "cron.php" ]
then
    $parse $parse_options cron.php
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]
    then
         echo "cron.php not parsed."
    else
         if $verbose
         then
             echo "cron.php has successfully been parsed."
         fi
    fi
else
    echo "cron.php not found."
    exit
fi

exit
```

and then the crontab itself:

```
$crontab -e
*/1 * * * * ~/scripts/cron-php.sh
```

**Third Solution is based on Drush**

[According to Drush Doc](http://www.drush.org/en/master/cron/)

```
0 */1 * * * /usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin COLUMNS=72 /usr/local/bin/drush --root=/usr/share/nginx/demo --uri=your.drupalsite.org --quiet cron
```

Comment: When I changed cron call to `*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /usr/share/nginx/demo/cron.php >> /var/log/demo-cron.log 2>&1`, I've got an error in cron.php `Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_bootstrap() in /usr/share/nginx/demo/cron.php on line 14` because getcwd() function returns incorrect path `/root` instead `/usr/share/nginx/demo`

Comment: @stan do you have drush on your server?

Comment: yes. version 8.0.1

Comment: @stan try the second solution while I'm going to provide another solution base on drush.drush solution is provided for you too.

Comment: both doesn't work. third solution doesn't run drupal cron like a simple curl or wget request. second solution can't run drupal cron, error "invalid cron key"

Comment: @stan are you sure about that ? what is your drupal version?  try to  go to your drupal path and run `php cron.php` manually ( for debug), do you see invalid cron key message?

Comment: i've ran `php cron.php` now. in result same error: cron can not be started because invalid key was used. Drupal version 7.53

Comment: @stan what do you mean ? running internally with `php` doesn't require key, did you pass some key to it ? or do you change something on settings.php about cron ?

Comment: i've tried to do it on another Drupal 7 site - same result, "invalid key". No settings changed

Comment: all solutions work for correctly :(. Ok, lets debug drush method.
try 'drush --root=/usr/share/nginx/demo  --quiet cron'   on command line( without crontab) inform me about the results.

Comment: Exactly what is needed! Now I see error. `Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                                                                                                 [error]
Error: Call to a member function queryReportFeed() on null in /usr/share/nginx/demo/sites/all/modules/google_analytics_counter/google_analytics_counter_data.inc, line 401`. zhilevan, many thanks. I think that now it  will be possible to fix it

Comment: @stan great, so finally we could find the problem and after resolving the issue it'll work for you. you're welcome.

Comment: yep! i'll report about finally result. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Running cron tasks before clear all your cache.
During development it is necessary to clear the cache very frequently.
Clearing caches is relatively harmless. Sites might slow down for a bit afterwards while the cache fills back up.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. How is the cache influences on cron tasks?

Comment: Yes, running cron.php still clear cache, as running the cron will call system_cron which calls "cache_clear_all" method.